# how to have an iMacros script expand a Facebook wall and then expand all comments

Tags: facebook, firefox, imacros

I am trying to expand out a Facebook wall and then display all comments on that expanded wall.

Manually, this would be achieved by accessing the link to the wall and then scrolling down continuously, causing progressively more of the page to display, until all of the page is displayed. Then, every instance of a selectable piece of text of the form `View * more comments` would be selected, causing all comments in the page to be displayed fully.

I have attempted to have the scrolling down events register with iMacros without success and I have had basic success with selecting the text `View 1 more comments` with the following script:

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/FACEBOOKID1?and=FACEBOOKID2
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:View<SP>1<SP>more<SP>comments
```

How can I automate the scrolling down behaviour and how can I improve on my current attempt at expanding comments to act in a more general way?

Answer (score 0):

I use the js-script below:

```
// set the number of scrolls you prefer
var scrollNumber = 1;
// scroll
for (i = 1; i <= scrollNumber; i++) {
    window.scrollTo(0, i*10000);
    iimPlayCode("WAIT SECONDS=2");
}
// expand comment boxes with 50 less comments
var doc = window.document;
var cmtBoxes = doc.getElementsByClassName("UFIBlingBox uiBlingBox feedbackBling");
for (i = 1; i <= cmtBoxes.length; i++) {
    var cmtLabel = cmtBoxes[i - 1].getAttribute("aria-label");
    var cmtNumber = cmtLabel.match(/.*\s(\d+)\scomments.*/)[1];
    if (cmtNumber < 50)
        iimPlayCode('TAG POS=' + i + ' TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"UFIBlingBox uiBlingBox feedbackBling"');
}
// count
var cmtPostNumber = 0;
for (i = 0; i < doc.links.length; i++) {
    if (doc.links[i].innerHTML.match(/View\s\d+\smore\scomment/) != null)
        cmtPostNumber++;
}
// view
for (i = 1; i <= cmtPostNumber; i++) {
    var M = "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1" + "\n";
    M += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:View<SP>*<SP>more<SP>comment*" + "\n";
    M += "WAIT SECONDS=1";
    var ret = iimPlayCode(M);
    if (ret != 1) break;
}
// go to the top
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```